# Tres Leche Without Homemade Cake?

Tags: substitutions, cake

I've been wanting to make a tres leche cake and I have a few cake box mixes at home (yellow cake, spice cake and a chocolate cake).  Could I use the yellow cake and then just fork it and pour over the tres leche sauce or is there something about typical tres leche cake recipes that makes them better suited to the sauce and the overall dish?

Comment: I think tres leches is usually more like a white cake. Not that yellow cake flavor is that strong or anything - but it would probably look a bit different, since cake mix yellow cake is pretty yellow.

Comment: Good point.  I guess that would be my little spin on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tres leches cake is always of the sponge variety.

It is much higher in eggs and the extra protein lets it hold up to sitting in a puddle of milk overnight. A regular white cake would not be a good plan. It would be at best pudding in the morning.

If you are trying to get rid of boxed cake and want it to be a sponge cake you could try beating egg whites and folding them into your batter.

Personally I think sponge cakes are so easy that I would rather just make the tres leches from scratch and save the boxed cake for a trifle or to give away to someone who doesn't care.

Comment: Okay, I'll save the box mixes for other occasions!  Thanks for your advice.